# Plot a tree from multiple adjacency matrices

Tags: python, data-visualization, networkx, graph-theory, igraph

I'm trying to plot a tree from multiple adjacency matrices. To better explain, I will do an example with 3 matrices. I have 3 matrices **a**, **b** and **c**. The rows of **a** point to the columns of **a**. The columns of **a**, that have the same name of the rows of **b**, point to the columns of **b**, and so on with the **c** matrix.

So, the **a** rows are the 1st level of the tree, the **b** rows (**a** columns) are the 2nd, the **c** rows (**b** columns) are the 3rd.

These are the adjacency matrices:

```
#Adjacency matrices 

a = [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]

b = [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

c = [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I convert them to pandas datafames to give the names to the nodes

```
import pandas as pd
data_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
data_a.index = ['0a','0b','0c'] 
data_a.columns = ['1a','1b','1c','1d','1e']

data_b = pd.DataFrame(b)
data_b.index = data_a.columns
data_b.columns = ['2a','2b','2c','2d','2e','2f','2g']

data_c = pd.DataFrame(c)
data_c.index = data_b.columns
data_c.columns = ['3a','3b','3c','3d','3e','3f','3g','3h','3i']
```

Data are now structured in this way:

[image: mat_a]

[image]

I would like to obtain, from these adjacency matrix, a tree with a structure like this, or any other graphical representation possible:

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to combine the three adjacency matrices a, b, c into a single adjacency matrix.

```
aa ab ..
ba bb bc
.. cb cc
```

Then you can use plot(layout=layout_with_sugiyama) in [R], [rigraph] to visualize a tree-like structure.